# Trick to give images a standard group size

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm not sure where to start with this:

I'm looking for a way to custom edit widths/heights on on line of photos, pretty much the exact same as here http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=flowers. On flickR each line of photos has the same width and each photo of that line the same height. so that it lines up nicely.

On my pages I use php to randomly select 2 or 3 images to display in a line, I have it set so the width is a set size (2 images at 50% or 3 at 33% witch etc) but that means the height is off between the images. The tidy solution is a script I guess that looks at the images height and widths and works out their sizes so that the widths and heights adjust to match up and keep a tidy line.

Does anyone know where to start with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could start by looking at this blog post:

http://www.crispymtn.com/stories/the-algorithm-for-a-perfectly-balanced-photo-gallery

Answer (score 4):

Generally i will place the images within an element, i.e.

```
<div class='item_image'><img src='image.jpg'></div>
```

You could then set css as follows:

```
div.item_image { width: 100px; height: 75px; overflow-y: hidden; }
div.item_image img { width: 100%; }
```

You could also use php to resize your images appropriately and/or create thumbnail sizes which are appropriate to what you need.. Lots of options really.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the images as `background-image` and then use the `background-size: cover` property to fill the containing elements. Just set a specific width & height of each image container, and then `background-size: cover` will fill the container with the image.

More on this here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

**Markup**

```
<div class="imageOne" style="background-image: url('x');"> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imageOne {
    background-size: cover;
}
```